# recommend jFrog repository package

Tags: software-development, cloud-storage, binary-data, jenkins

We are using **jFrog** software/service and I need to create repository there, but I'm struggling to chose what type of repository/package I should choose. Please suggest some for my needs. In my release pipeline I'm generating 3 binaries for each OS (Win, Mac, Linux), each has also folder with .json config files, they will be archived(.zip/etc) along with binaries and sent to the artifactory. So what is the best place to store these archives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use Generic type. Alternative for artifactory was to use S3 Bucket